# Flutter Custom Keyboard ('Fake' soft keyboard)

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, dart, flutter

I'm working on a finance app and I'd like a custom textentry field and keyboard for currency entry with an inbuilt calculator.

I've tried using a BottomSheet, both persistent and modal. The modal behaviour is ideal, but it always shows a barrier. The persistent one is what I have now, using a focus node to show and hide it, but it's throwing strange errors:

```
I/flutter (30319): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while dispatching notifications for FocusNode:
I/flutter (30319): The method 'removeLocalHistoryEntry' was called on null.
I/flutter (30319): Receiver: null
I/flutter (30319): Tried calling: removeLocalHistoryEntry(Instance of 'LocalHistoryEntry')
I/flutter (30319):
I/flutter (30319): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (30319): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:46:5)
I/flutter (30319): #1      LocalHistoryEntry.remove (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:296:12)
I/flutter (30319): #2      _NumpadFieldState.initState.<anonymous closure> (file:///D:/code/financepie/lib/widgets/numpad/numpadfield.dart:30:32)
...
```

In any case, the bottom sheet behaviour (dragging down) isn't really ideal to copy the android/ios soft keyboard. Any better solutions? Current code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'numpad.dart';

class NumpadField extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _NumpadFieldState createState() {
    return new _NumpadFieldState();
  }
}

class _NumpadFieldState extends State<NumpadField> {
  ValueNotifier<List<String>> state;
  FocusNode focusNode;
  PersistentBottomSheetController bottomSheetController;

  @override initState() {
    super.initState();
    state = ValueNotifier<List<String>>([]);
    state.addListener(() => setState((){}));
    focusNode = FocusNode();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      print(focusNode);
      if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
        bottomSheetController = showBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => Numpad(state: state),
        );
      } else {
        bottomSheetController?.close(); ///this line causing the error
      }
    }); 
  }
  @override dispose() {
    state.dispose();
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Text(state.value.fold<String>("", (str, e) => "$str $e")),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 24.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: BorderDirectional(bottom: BorderSide())
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that you should not be using bottom sheets for that. You can either integrate it into your layout or use [an Overlay](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Overlay/of.html) (what I linked is just a starting point for you).

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot I think you're right. One thought - could I use a ModalRoute? Would the textfield update in the 'background' route while the keyboard is open?

Comment: I've tried to run your but the system detected an error in `import 'numpad.dart';`. Could you provide more context about that particular import? Is it a plugin or a separate class you've created?

Comment: It's the keyboard implementation. However in the end I used an Overlay or something like that, afraid I can't remember now

Comment: Could you share your solution here?

Answer (score 0):

`bottomSheetController?.close();` is nullable. Since the line causes the error, you can add a null-check to prevent this issue.

```dart
else {
  if(bottomSheetController != null)
      bottomSheetController!.close();
}
```